# The difference between ぐらい and ばかり

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I want to know more about the difference between ぐらい and ばかり, and when either should be used. For example in the 2 sentences below. I think either of them can be used.

> 駅まで2時間ぐらいで着くと思います。

> 駅まで2時間ばかりで着くと思います。

But for the sentences below, it will have a different meaning

> 30分ぐらい座りました

> 30分ばかり座りました

In my assumption, ぐらい is "about", and ばかり is "only about"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, ばかり has a connotation of “only” even when it is used as a synonym of ぐらい. However, I would say that difference is pretty subtle and rather negligible.

I see a much bigger difference between the two. ばかり is not very frequently used in that sense any longer, at least not in spoken language. I may see it from time to time in writing but hardly ever hear anyone actually say it in a conversation. It would sound a bit stilted.

ばかり in the sense of “only” is commonly used  in conversation, often in the colloquial form of ばっかり.

> 彼は文句ば（っ）かり言う。
> He does nothing but complain.

If you need to express the meaning of "approximately" somewhat formally, you can use ほど instead of ぐらい.

> 駅まで2時間ほどで着くと思います。

> 30分ほど座りました。